# Brilliant.org replaceable of standard textbook and classes?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am using Brilliant.org  for learning Calculus, Linear Algebra and different topics . I am  home-schooled and wanted to grasp all the content of calculus and linear  algebra in a fruitful way . But I don't see a standard topic wise and  clear definition of formulas and theorem. Do it will help me to learn  the calculus and linear algebra like how a college or university is  providing material to their student ? And what about mit opencourseware  and khan academy for calculus and Linear Algebra in context of brilliant.org ?

Comment: Brilliant in my opinion is not great for learning material by itself, but it is a good place to find challenging, supplemental problems.

Comment: I suggest consulting with someone who is familiar with these subjects and who is familiar with you.  Failing that, I'd just use the curriculum materials used by your local school or college.